# Access or modify tnsnames.ora on AWS Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, scala, amazon-web-services

I am trying to access an Oracle RDS instance running on AWS via a Scala Play app using `ojdbc8` driver. I need to access the `tnsnames.ora` file and check its configuration since I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

which is directly connected these two following resolutions

- [How to Fix 'ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor'](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-fix-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor/)
- [TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/listener-refused-the-connection-with-following-error-ora-12505-tns-listener-d)

the problem is that AWS [does NOT allow remote access to the Oracle RDS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=38599) and I cannot find anything in the AWS console which would help me change or even access the contents of the `tnsnames.ora`.

Can I maybe do it using SQL? This error does not even seem to be consistent since for example, some queries do work....

///
More info:

Queries like the following are successfully executed:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (

SELECT
  DISTINCT tab.column_a, tab.column_a AS L0, tab.column_a AS L1, tab.column_a AS L2
FROM
  ADMIN.table_something tab
WHERE
  tab.column_a IS NOT NULL 

)
```

the ones that fail look like this

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT tab.column_a, tab.column_a AS L0, tab.column_a AS L1, tab.column_a AS L2
FROM
  ADMIN.table_something tab
WHERE
  tab.column_a IS NOT NULL
```

and by fail I mean producing the error I mentioned above. Executing these from a SQL command prompt produces no errors.

I am using this jdbc URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_URL>:1521:SID
```

I also tried using this format

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_URL>:1521/ServiceNames
```

But apparently the AWS RDS instance is not configured with service names since there is a syntax error produced if I use one. Most of the answers I've found refer to the `tnsnames.ora` as the place where the service names and SIDs are configured and therefore includes information on how to actually form a connection string. This is why I want to access it and if I find something suspicious then modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the error was the queryString. Somewhere in the code the followng query parameter was appended to the query string: `useCursorFetch=true`. This was initially added to support MySQL databases but it stayed there for all other as well. For Oracle then, then connection URL was transformed to the following:

- `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host_URL>:1521:SID?useCursorFetch=true`

which of course was interpreted as an invalid SID from Oracle.

I still think though that there should be a straightforward way to inspect the
`tnsnames.ora` file.